# Is ServiceStack ORMLite available for .NET Core

Tags: servicestack, .net-core

I saw some commits for ServiceStakck ORMLite for .NET Core specifically [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/707e85a1558a8e049bed57e4cf62092e225260d9)

Can we try it right now or it is just nuget spec update? I am looking to integrate ServiceStack ORMLite for .Net core project (ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL.Core).

Comment: It's not ready yet - we have .NET Core builds but are still testing them, it will be ready in the next v4.5.2 release of ServiceStack

Comment: Thanks. When are you guys planning to release v4.5.2 ?

Comment: We don't have set dates for releases, but the OrmLite.Core packages that are on NuGet now should ideally be ready by the end of the week.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also great work on ServiceStack.

Comment: FYI see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39684977/85785) for how to use PostgreSQL OrmLite in .NET Core Apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of [OrmLite's supported packages](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#download) contains both **.NET Framework v4.5** and **.NET Standard 2.0** builds which can be used in both .NET Framework and .NET Core projects which can be used like normal:

```
public class Person
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static string PostgreSqlDb = "{Connection String}";

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
            PostgreSqlDb, PostgreSqlDialect.Provider);

        using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
        {
            db.DropAndCreateTable<Person>();

            5.Times(i => db.Insert(new Person { Name = "Name {i}" }));

            var results = db.Select<Person>();

            results.PrintDump();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for you help.

Answer (score 0):

As say in  NuGet package's [details page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL.Core/), you can use it with .Net Core with at least .NETStandard 1.3.

But if you look into the latest [release note](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.5.0.md#net-core-support-for-servicestackredis). They say :

> Just like the other .NET Core libraries .NET Core builds of
>   ServiceStack.Redis is released with a *.Core suffix until development
>   of .NET Core has stabilized.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks a lot.